# Using two streams in Java lambda to compute covariance

Tags: java, lambda, statistics, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have two arrays of double.
I've been experimenting with Stream from Java 8. I think I've understood the main ideas
but then I realised that I'm not sure how to manipulate two Streams at the same time.

For example, I want to calculate the covariance of both arrays.

```
public class foo {

    public static double mean(double[] xs) {
        return Arrays.stream(xs).average().getAsDouble();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] xs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        double[] ys = {1517.93, 1757.78, 1981.1, 2215.73, 2942.66, 3558.32, 4063.91, 4521.16, 5101.76, 5234.12};

        System.out.println("Mean of xs: " + mean(xs));
        double xs_sumDeviation = Arrays.stream(xs)
            .boxed()
            .mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue() - mean(xs))
            .sum();
       // Covariance
        double covXY = Arrays.stream(xs, ys)
            .mapToDouble(x,y -> {
                  double numerator = (x-mean(xs)* (y-mean(ys);
                  double denominator = Math.sqrt((x-mean(xs)* (x-mean(xs));
                  return numerator / denominator;
             })
            .sum();

    }
}
```

Thank you for suggestions.

Attempt 1.

```
public static double covariance(double[] xs, double[] ys) {
    double xmean = mean(xs);
    double ymean = mean(ys);
    double numerator = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(xs.length, ys.length))
            .parallel()
            .mapToDouble(i -> (xs[i] - xmean) * (ys[i] - ymean))
            .sum();
    double denominator = Math.sqrt(IntStream.range(0, xs.length)
            .parallel()
            .mapToDouble(i -> (xs[i] - xmean) * (xs[i] - xmean))
            .sum());
    return numerator / denominator;
```

Comment: And what's the question again?

Comment: Sorry. The question was how to implement java lambda expression to calculate the covariance of two arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other programming languages, there is some kind of *zip* function, that takes several *iterables*, and returns an *iterator* that aggregates elements from each of the *iterables*. See for example the function [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the Python Library.

Although it would be possible to make a similar function in Java, it's hard to implement it in such a way, that it supports efficient parallel execution. However, there is a commonly used pattern in Java, that is a bit different. In your case, it might look as follows:

```
public static double covariance(double[] xs, double[] ys) {
    double xmean = mean(xs);
    double ymean = mean(ys);
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(xs.length, ys.length))
        .parallel()
        .mapToDouble(i -> {
                double numerator = (xs[i] - xmean) * (ys[i] - ymean);
                double denominator = ...;
                return numerator / denominator;
            })
        .sum();
}
```

Instead of combining two streams, you create an `IntStream` with all indexes, and you access the elements of the different collections by index. That works pretty well as long as the collections support random access operations.

Comment: Thank you. Now I learn another way of using lambda expression. The function Math.sqrt() should be applied to the denominator only after the summation. I guess that's why you wrote the ... But does that imply I have to calculate the denominator in another Stream?

Comment: @CheJharia: I used the `...` to focus on the essentials. The intention was to keep the original semantics. It would help to see a non-stream implementation of your covariance functions, because there are different kinds of _variance_ and _covariance_.

Answer (score 3):

Other FP languages have the `zip` operation, which makes a stream of *pairs* from two streams of elements. This has not been made available in Java.

In case of arrays, however, you can easily make a stream of *array indices* and let your functions close over the arrays, accessing them by the index parameter.

I should also warn you that in this line

```
.mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue() - mean(xs))
```

you are making your program complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>) because `mean` is recalculated at each step. You should precalculate that and close over the result in the lambda.